# Linux: How to sort a given directory by time and list down the size of the files/directories

Tags: linux, bash

In Linux, you can use

```
ls -lt <dir>
```

to list the files/directories based on the modification time.

You can also use

```
du -hs <dir>/*
```

to find out the size.

How can I combine both to obtain the size of the time sorted files/directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
command ls -dt */ | while IFS= read -r dir; do du -sh "$dir"; done
```

This works on the directories in the current directory.
It will break if any directory name contains a newline.

Answer (score 0):

try below options:

> ls -lt | xargs du -hs

or

> du -hs * | sort -h

or

> du -k * | sort -nr | cut -f2 | xargs -d '\n' du -sh

Comment: I got lots of errors (e.g. du: invalid option -- 'r') when executing first command. Also does "sort -h" sort by modification time?

Comment: Try this:   
    ls -tr | xargs -d '\n' du -sh